# Installing Cinnamon on Ubuntu 12.04 (running on VirtualBox)

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, gnome-3

So I've installed the Cinnamon desktop environment on my Virtual machine but it looks exactly the same as the classic Gnome desktop (fact, I tried installing Gnome 3 and it looks the same as classic as well). My video memory is set at the max (128 MB). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that your virtual machine does not have access to the accelerated graphics hardware and therefore the session falls back to gnome classic. Try it on a physical desktop.

Comment: I recall getting Gnome 3 to work on my virtual machine running 11.10 though

Answer (score 0):

**You have to enable 3D acceleration in settings**. And make sure about 64MB or more video memory is given. Then cinnamon will work. Otherwise it will fall back to gnome 2 classic.

See proof.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/gizfm.jpg

Comment: I've got 3D acceleration and 128 MB of video memory allocated. Still no luck. Could you walk-through the process you took?

Comment: Did you install VirtualBox Addons?